# Read two lines of a file at once in a flink streaming process

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I want to process files with a flink stream in which two lines belong together. In the first line there is a header and in the second line a corresponding text.

The files are located on my local file system. I am using the `readFile(fileInputFormat, path, watchType, interval, pathFilter, typeInfo)`  method with a custom `FileInputFormat`.

My streaming job class looks like this:

```
final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
DataStream<Read> inputStream = env.readFile(new ReadInputFormatTest("path/to/monitored/folder"), "path/to/monitored/folder", FileProcessingMode.PROCESS_CONTINUOUSLY, 100);
inputStream.print();
env.execute("Flink Streaming Java API Skeleton");
```

and my `ReadInputFormatTest` like this:

```
public class ReadInputFormatTest extends FileInputFormat<Read> {

    private transient FileSystem fileSystem;
    private transient BufferedReader reader;
    private final String inputPath;
    private String headerLine;
    private String readLine;

    public ReadInputFormatTest(String inputPath) {
        this.inputPath = inputPath;
    }

    @Override
    public void open(FileInputSplit inputSplit) throws IOException {
        FileSystem fileSystem = getFileSystem();
        this.reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileSystem.open(inputSplit.getPath())));
        this.headerLine = reader.readLine();
        this.readLine = reader.readLine();
    }

    private FileSystem getFileSystem() {
        if (fileSystem == null) {
            try {
                fileSystem = FileSystem.get(new URI(inputPath));
            } catch (URISyntaxException | IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
        return fileSystem;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean reachedEnd() throws IOException {
        return headerLine == null;
    }

    @Override
    public Read nextRecord(Read r) throws IOException {
        r.setHeader(headerLine);
        r.setSequence(readLine);

        headerLine = reader.readLine();
        readLine = reader.readLine();

        return r;
    }
}
```

As expected, the headers and the text are stored together in one object. However, the file is read eight times. So the problem is the parallelization. Where and how can I specify that a file is processed only once, but several files in parallel?
Or do I have to change my custom `FileInputFormat` even further?

Answer (score 0):

I would modify your source to emit the available filenames (instead of the actual file contents) and then add a new processor to read a name from the input stream and then emit pairs of lines.  In other words, split the current source into a source followed by a processor.  The processor can be made to run at any degree of parallelism and the source would be a single instance.

Comment: I am a total newbie to flink and haven't found much about how to just read filenames into a stream yet. I only came across how to include the file content. Do you know an example on this subject?
By a processor you mean a map call to the file name Stream? 
Wouldn't I get a strem with arrays/lists of objects back afterwards instead of a stream of the single objects?